# Merge contiguous partitions /swap, /var, /tmp, /home in a single one on Debian 10

Tags: debian, partition

I did wrong when I installed my first `Debian 9` that is now a `Debian 10`, and chosen a :
`/home` partition with 180 Gb
`/var` partition with 10 Gb, too small
`/tmp` partition with 2 Gb, too small

I am bored with these partitions. I would like to merge them into a single one containing `/home`, `/var` and `/tmp` and have no more stories with limitations.

How do I merge `/var`, `/tmp`, `/swap`, `/home` partitions (going from `/dev/sda5` to `/dev/sda8` in my case and are contiguous)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, *merging* file-systems is generally not feasible

It is, in theory, possible to do what you want, but far too exotic for a tool to exist already. To save yourself a lot of headache, and unless you are on really low income, you are better off by purchasing a second disk and copy the data. You get a free back-up for your data as a bonus.

1. Have a second Linux (a live medium is sufficient).
2. Create the desired amount of partitions (I usually have only one) on the new disk.
3. Copy your data (start with the biggest, `/home` in your case, using `e2image -rap`, then `rsync -a` for the rest).
4. Adjust `/etc/fstab`.
5. Boot into the copied system (using the second Linux or something like the Super Grub 2 Disk).
6. Install and configure the boot-loader.
7. Enjoy.

As for merging not being feasible: You have a number of separate partitions. There is a file-system on each of the partitions (I assume ext4). Most general purpose file-systems can grow or shrink, but there is – as far as I know – not a single file-system whose instances are designed to be merged. You could – in theory – gather all inodes (the meta-information which organizes the files) of the second file-system, expand the first file-system over the second one, inject the gathered inodes into the first file-system, adjusting the file-on-disk position information by the file-system's offsets. This rough list of things in need to be done is not exhaustive.
Now that I summed it up, it does not even look terribly dangerous to do this. Assuming one knows the file-system's internals reasonably well, one could write a tool for this purpose. However, since simply copying the user data does the job just as well, so no professional ever did.

Comment: Can you enlighten us as to why this is not possible?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Is is possible (I updated my answer), but not feasible (I do not know a tool nor ever heard of one).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Just now I realized that a one-pass merge without copying was not explicitly requested. I cannot down-vote my own answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. Except don't merge swap, and first back-up (at least back up what you can't get back).

1. Backup
2. Boot with a live OS. Don't do this on an active system.
3. Migrate `/var` and `/tmp` to `/` or `/home`: Copy them over, then change mount table, so that they are not mounted. If you migrate them to `/home`, then create links to them.
4. Test
5. When it is all working.

   1. Delete partitions `/var` and `/tmp`
   2. resize `/home` partition to fill the gap.

Comment: And the best way to deal with the swap partition is to delete it temporarily, and then recreate it once the other partitions have been merged. `/tmp` can also be deleted without merging, and perhaps replaced with a `tmpfs`.